# OpenSolaris: Remove user from a group from command line

Tags: command-line-interface, solaris, groups, opensolaris

How can I remove a user from a group from the command line in OpenSolaris (2008.11)?

I know I can define a user's primary group and a add a user to a group with:

```
usermod -g primarygroup user
usermod -G group_list user
```

What's the corresponding command to undo that action and remove a user from the group without just editing /etc/groups

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:
`usermod -G "" username`

That should remove them from the extra group. This appears to work in SOL10/OSOL/Linux. It's worth noting that'll remove them from ALL extra groups. If you want to just remove them from one just get their current groups list: `id username`

Then just build the list of extra groups to add with `usermod -G` and don't add the one you want to take them out of.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer applies to Debian, but maybe it will work on OpenSolaris as well.

Run `usermod -g another_group user` (modifies `/etc/passwd`), and/or run `usermod -G group_list user` (modifies `/etc/group`).